# Can I use a PWM controller to control the speed of a motor?

Tags: pwm, dc-motor

First off, I’m starting electronics as a hobby so excuse my lack of knowledge about electronics in general.

As a staring project, I was going to try and make a magnetic stirrer to use in a chemistry project. I was intending on attaching a magnet to a gear motor and control the speed using a PWM controller.

My question is: Is it ok if I use a PWM controller to manage the speed of the motor, considering it is a gear motor? I’m using a DC current of 12V 1A. The PWM module should lower the peak voltage, therefore lowering the speed of the motor right? Also, I searched the motor up and I couldn’t find a current rating. Is it ok if I use 1Amp?

Again, I apologize for my lackluster knowledge about the subject, but I did do research, although I could not find anything regarding to this topic.

Gear Motor https://www.amazon.co.uk/Motor-50-2000RPM-Speed-Reduction-Gearbox/dp/B07SR9GSR9

and

PWM controller https://www.amazon.co.uk/Controller-Adjustable-Stepless-Governor-Regulator/dp/B078TC3DTX

Comment: In principle PWM is a viable approach.  But in specific, "will [sales link] work with [sales link]?" fails the requirement that questions stand on their own.

Comment: @Electric_90 please don't hide link targets, especially when they are sales links.  Being able to see their destination is important to realizing that this question is *insufficiently documented* and critically relies on pages likely to quickly go offline, a fact which is counter to stack exchange guidelines.

Comment: "Rated Voltage: DC 3V... Voltage Range: DC 1.5V-5V... Rated Voltage: DC 6V
Voltage Range: DC 3V-9V... Rated Voltage: DC 12V" - with specs like these...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally abrupt starts to Motors will draw up to 10x the rated current in the 1st cycle and then reduce to the stable value when acceleration reaches the final velocity.

If one considers the heat rise of over current and the application does not demand rapid changes in  speed then the current rating can be reduced from 10x the motor rating to much less. Spinning a magnet is not much of a load compared to abrupt turn on to max speed.

Speed control is done by changing the average duty cycle of the supplied pulsed voltage not by reducing the peak amplitude.

Therefore a 30A PWM is a good choice for a 1A motor with 10A worst case expected surges even if draws  < 1 A at steady speed.  One might consider a smaller rating, but at this cost, reliability is improved by over-design as there is often little or no active cooling.

> Stable low speed settings should not be expected if the load changes.  This only controls average voltage and not power or RPM.

[image]